# Query from multiple servers using power query

Tags: sql, excel

I have two stored procedures on two SQL servers each queries the same tables etc. on each server. Is there a way to Query both simultaneously? to combine data into one result set.
While passing parameters to them?

Example:
Company a on server a stored procedure name SP_A

```
DECLARE
@From_date as varchar(10) = '20210101'
@To_date as varchar(10) = '20210601'

SELECT Product, price, orderNum
FROM a where order date = between @From_date and @To_date
```

Company b on server b stored procedure name SP_B

```
DECLARE
@From_date as varchar(10) = '20210101'
@To_date as varchar(10) = '20210601'

SELECT Product, price, orderNum
FROM b where order date = between @From_date and @To_date
```

EXCEL :

```
exec a.SP_A @From_date = C1, @To_date = C2, exec SP_B @From_date = C1, @To_date = C2
```

Hope this explains clearly what I am trying to do here any insight will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For my case Achieving this turned out to be quite straightforward, as the servers I was querying are linked together. So only follow this solution for linked servers.

Create a stored procedure:
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [scheme].[master_meat_PO]    Script Date: 15/09/2021 15:13:10 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [scheme].[master_meat_PO]

```
@from as datetime = '20200101',
@to as datetime = '20210814'

as

begin

SELECT Product, price, orderNum
FROM SQL_a.db_a.Scheme_a.table_a 
where order date = between @From_date and @To_date

UNION

SELECT Product, price, orderNum
FROM SQL_b.db_b.Scheme_b.table_b 
where order date = between @From_date and @To_date
```

Then simply call the procedure as usual in Excel:

```
exec a.SP_A @From_date = C1, @To_date = C2, exec SP_B @From_date = C1, @To_date = C2
```